# TextBox OnPaint method is not called?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, onpaint

I have use the following code to create a textbox, but the paint method is not triggered at any situation of the textbox. Can you suggest a solution to trigger the OnPaint() ?

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics,this.Bounds, Color.Red,ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        this.Refresh();
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug that it is not hit? Your `DrawBorder` call maybe useless, because you call `base.OnPaint()` _after_ that. So the `TextBox` draws itself again _over_ what you painted before.

Answer (score 22):

OnPaint will not be called on a TextBox by default unless you register it as a self-painting control, by making a call to :

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

e.g. from your MyTextBox constructor.

Comment: @VenkateshKs If this answered your question please mark it as the answer to help future users who have similar quesitons.

Comment: This fixed the triggering event problem but messed up the way textbox operates.

Comment: This may call OnPaint but now it's painted by the system in a tiny font with a tiny caret, and my own OnPaint method gets overdrawn. Switching to a RichTextbox allowed me to paint it myself but the caret is still drawn by the system.

Comment: Like René Vogt has mentioned; Paint Event is NOT Supported by the Default TextBox and using: SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true) is NOT Viable.
IMHO to customize the TextBox; it is preferrable to create a User Control (derived from a TextBox) for this Purpose.
Takes a little work and time but it would work and perform better, than attempting modify the base Control.

Answer (score 4):

You need to switch the calls in your `OnPaint`

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.Bounds, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

`base.OnPaint()` draws the `TextBox` as usual. If you call `DrawBorder` *before* the `base` call, it is overpainted by the base implementation again.

---

But according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.paint), the `Paint` event is not supported by `TextBox`:

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
>   Occurs when the control is redrawn. This event is not relevant for this class.

So Ben Jackon's answer should solve that problem.

Comment: Thats ok. i am asking hit the OnPaint method.

Comment: i am asking triggered the OnPaint method. because this method was not triggered.

Comment: @VenkateshKs alright, Ben got the answer. I leave this post as the call order is still a relevant problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was create the graphics object after the window receives the [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message.

***C#***

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(m);
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            BackgroundText();
            break;
    }
}

private void BackgroundText()
{
    if (DesignMode)
    {
        using (Graphics G = CreateGraphics())
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(G, "Project No.", new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25), new Point(3, 1), Color.FromArgb(94, 101, 117));
        }
        return;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
    {
        using (Graphics G = CreateGraphics())
        {
            Color tColor = FindForm.ActiveControl == this ? Color.FromArgb(94, 101, 117) : SystemColors.Window;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(G, "Project No.", new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25), new Point(3, 1), tColor);
        }
    }
}
```

***VB.NET***

```vb
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_PAINT
                BackgroundText()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundText()
        If DesignMode Then
            Using G As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                TextRenderer.DrawText(G, "Project No.", New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25), New Point(3, 1), Color.FromArgb(94, 101, 117))
            End Using
            Return
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) Then
            Using G As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                Dim tColor As Color = If(FindForm.ActiveControl Is Me, Color.FromArgb(94, 101, 117), SystemColors.Window)
                TextRenderer.DrawText(G, "Project No.", New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25), New Point(3, 1), tColor)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```